# Show html email status under account

Tags: email, account, activities

Is it possible to show html email status along with activity history related list in accounts? Right now i have to click on the contact then only i can see the html status.

What i have tried:
Adding a custom vf page into account layout.
Problem: I cannot query EmailStatus Object.

Then i though i will add a repeater in that page with account's contacts and add a component which uses standard contact controller and get the EmailStatus related list.

But later i came to know that you cannot use standard contoller with a component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you cannot query the object directly but you could query the parent of the EmailStatus, for example the contact and it's children records and filter it by account:

```
Select Name, AccountId, (Select Id, EmailTemplateName From EmailStatuses) From Contact WHERE AccountId = '0018000000QbytrAAB'
```

Comment: Sadly, even though `Task` object has this child relationship too (per Workbench), it's only queryable from `Contacts` and `Accounts` per Jenny's example.

Comment: I meant to say from `Contacts` and `Leads`, not `Accounts`

Answer (score 6):

Shanker

As per [this reference](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=email_track.htm&language=en_US), HTML Email Status Related list is available only for Leads, Contacts and Person Accounts which has the standard email field.

if your question is about adding it to Person Accounts then you can go to Person Account page layout and add it.

but if its for normal Accounts which doesn't have a standard Email field, you cannot add this related list directly. You need to build a visualforce page which can display the related list from the associated Contact and then you can add this VF page into the Standard Account page layout.

Comment: VF page into the Standard Account page layout. how can i do it?

Comment: Hi i can to know how to add visualforce page. But the EmailStatus object is not queriable is there any workaround?