# Retrieving EmailStatus for Email related to Account

Tags: email, singleemailmessage

We are creating an email via Apex code:

```
    for (LeadOrContactTarget contact : contacts) {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setTargetObjectId(contact.id);
        mail.setTemplateId(templateId);
        mail.setWhatId(objectId);
        mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
        mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId('0D20Y000000kAa8SAE'); 
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });

        EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(
                HtmlBody=mail.getHtmlBody(),
                RelatedToId=accountId,
                Subject=mail.getSubject(),
                Status='3',
                ToAddress = contact.email
        ); // '3' = Sent
        upsert(message);
    }
```

Given that we create the Activity manually , we wrongly set it RelatedTo the account. Is there a way to query the EmailStatus for those email? It appears it is only related to Lead or Contact

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to query the EmailMessage SObject?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_EmailMessage.htm

There the Status field sounds promising.

Comment: It is not status, from the official docs: Read only. The status of the email. For example, New, Draft, Unread, Replied, or Sent.

Comment: What about MessageDate? Not sure, but this could be a SentDate. At least I would check if unsent mails might have this field blank. The fields of that object are maybe the best you can get, so I would examine them in detail.

Answer (score 0):

EmailStatus is not available via Apex

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ZzZUAA0

You could only loopback and callout to the SOAP api via Apex

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_emailstatus.htm

Comment: Is it available via Soap or Rest API?